# Open a Android device,then Settings > Developer Options > Pointer Location and toggle that on,

Tags: android, pointers, location, settings

I want to  know  where are the source codes of Pointer Location, I try to find the source code in Settings ,but I only get the following code, where are the source code that implents the effect of toggling Pointer Location on  ??????

**1.DevelopmentSettings.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, 
  Preference preference) {
    if (preference == mEnableAdb) {
        .....................
     } else if (preference == mPointerLocation) {
        writePointerLocationOptions();
     } else if (................) {
         .....................
     } else {
         .....................
     }

}
```

**2.writePointerLocationOptions()**

```
private void writePointerLocationOptions() {
    Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.POINTER_LOCATION, mPointerLocation.isChecked() ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find it here:

com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.enablePointerLocation()

Comment: Just wondering but you wouldn't know how to implement this in an app by any chance?